# Babel not allowing imports without .js file extension

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have installed babel and can now use import syntax for example. However, this code `import { dbConnect } from './utils/dbConnect.js';` works but this code `import { dbConnect } from './utils/dbConnect';` does not work.

I have been searching for hours online, and from what I understand, this functionality should be auto enabled in @babel/preset-env that I already have installed.
Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.14",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4"
  }
```

I currently do not have a `.babelrc` file.

Here is the error:

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/me/Repositories/myrepo/server/utils/dbConnect' imported from /Users/me/Repositories/myrepo/server/index.js
Did you mean to import ../utils/dbConnect.js?
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:276:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:699:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:88:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:241:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:56:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:55:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

Comment: So what is the error you get? "does not work" is not a useful description.

Comment: @loganfsmyth apologies i thought the description was enough. Edited my OP to include the error.

Comment: That error doesn't appear to be from Babel, though it is hard to tell without the stacktrace. Are you using Node's native module? (As in `"type":"module"` in your `package.json`?)

Comment: Yes my package.json is of type module. Ill try to post the full trace when I get back home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up enabling imports without file extension with the following:
`--experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node` added to the node while running my app.

My start script is now: `"start": "nodemon --exec babel-node --require dotenv/config --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node index.js"`

Comment: I have the same problem, but this start script didn't solve it :(

Comment: sadly it doesn't work for me either, @HasanaghaAliyev where you able to later solve it?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Node's builtin ES module support via `"type": "module"` or `.mjs` then you are opting into more restrictive requirements. [Node requires you to explicitly provide file extensions](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions) as part of that.

Babel's official plugins don't have any logic to add extensions, since that's not really related to ECMAScript as a language/specification. You could consider user a community plugin like https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-import-extension, which appears to support what you're looking for.

Comment: How do I make it that i can import .js files without specifying the file extension? I am confused, cause I thought that babel would take care of those and when transforming the code, it would add the file extension at the end.